# How to create an object a random number of times?

Tags: python

I'm creating a manager class that has method to create a `turtle` object.
Now I want to use the class to generate an object a random number of times.
How would I generate random numbers of objects?

This is my class:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]


class CarManager(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_car()

    def create_car(self):
        self.color(random.choice(COLORS))
        self.shape("square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=4)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(280, random.randint(-280, 280))
        self.setheading(180)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What code structure would you use to do something X times? Use that, except "X" is your random number and "something" is create an object of your class.

Answer (score -1):

Do you just want to create a random number of CarManager instances?

```
car_managers = []
for x in range(random.randint(0, 100)):
    car_managers.append(CarManager())
```

Answer (score -1):

you can modify the create car method to take parameters to allow more randomization
but to create random number of cars use

```
for i in range(random.randint(1,<max number u want>):
      carManger.create_car()
```